# What does OAKLEY stand for?

Tags: ipsec, ike

IPsec uses ISAKMP + OAKLEY + SKEME right? This is strange but even after checking  the [RFC of OAKLEY](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2412), i couldnt find what it basically stands for? Can someone please point me to the right direction or answer me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> IPsec uses ISAKMP + OAKLEY + SKEME right?

Current IPsec implementations actually use [IKEv2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296). But its predecessor, IKEv1, was based on these protocols. The introduction of [RFC 2409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409) (IKEv1) puts it this way:

> This document describes a protocol using part of Oakley and part of
> SKEME in conjunction with ISAKMP to obtain authenticated keying
> material for use with ISAKMP, and for other security associations
> such as AH and ESP for the IETF IPsec DOI.

As to your question what OAKLEY stands for: The author, Hilarie Orman, originally wrote it as Oakley in her [first draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ipsec-oakley-00), which indicates that it might not have been an acronym. Instead the protocol was apparently named after [Annie Oakley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annie_Oakley), which [she explained](http://m.pediy.com/showthread.php?t=126647) as follows (responding to someone from China asking the same question):

> Orman-Authenticated-Key-Exchange = OAKE Pronounced as "Oak-E" it sounds like a derogatory regional term in the USA. That was not acceptable, so it had to change slightly.

> Therefore, it became "Oakley" as in "Annie Oakley" the name of a female rodeo performer in the early American West. Because I am a woman, and because Annie Oakley was a woman renowned for her excellence in activities that were usually done by men, and because the IETF is mostly men, I thought that the name was an amusing.